# Pandas dataframe covert wide to long multiple columns with name from column Name

Tags: python, pandas

Consider I have a Pandas Dataframe with the following format.

```
Date           Product cost|us|2019    cost|us|2020    cost|us|2021  cost|de|2019    cost|de|2020  cost|de|2021
01/01/2020     prodA   10              12              14            12              13            15
```

How can we convert it into the following format?

```
Date         Product      Year     cost|us      cost|de
01/01/2020   ProdA        2019     10           12
01/01/2020   ProdA        2020     12           13
01/01/2020   ProdA        2021     14           15
```

Answer (score 2):

Convert non year columns to `MultiIndex` by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), then use [`str.rsplit`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rsplit.html) by columns by last `|`, set new column nmae in [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) and reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df = df.set_index(['Date','Product'])
df.columns = df.columns.str.rsplit('|', n=1, expand=True)
df = df.rename_axis([None, 'Year'], axis=1).stack().reset_index()
print (df)
         Date Product  Year  cost|de  cost|us
0  01/01/2020   prodA  2019       12       10
1  01/01/2020   prodA  2020       13       12
2  01/01/2020   prodA  2021       15       14
```